# How to pass Dockerfile or docker-compose in Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I saw that you can run containers using your own Dockerfile or docker-compose by executing Azure CLI.
But is it possible to specify a Dockerfile or dockercompose which will contain a link to the image and also some variables for the run-tim but through the Azure Portal and not Azure CLI?
I am referring to ACI type of containers.

Thanks

Comment: Are you answering about Azure WebApp with Docker integration?

Comment: Sorry, for now just ACI. Thanks I will add it to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can built the docker container locally or with a CI/CD pipeline and upload it to a container registry (Azure CR or Docker hub).

when creating an Azure Container Instance you can retrieve it from this repository

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I would actually like to specify Dockerfile which has the image link within it self and then in that Dockerfile I am specifying different variables which can be different per each ACI instance - so I am using the same image but runtime values can be different. That is why I would like to specify not an image but dockerfile which will pull already existing image and run the container with its commands and values. Thanks

Comment: In the docker file you changes environment variables?

Comment: Yes or some values within the Windows registry

Comment: you can't use dockerfiles for variables, but you can use the following way to use variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-environment-variables

if you then have the container image in a  container repository, the variables are applied to the image